# Jmeter - Unable to move to next iteration when an ERROR occurs

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am using the following code in BeanShell postprocessor to stop the current iteration on an error and move to the next iteration. But in my case, I am handling the duration programmatically(infinite while loop and time functions) and not using the thread group loop/duration. So loop count is set to default one at thread group level.

My jmeter script would be -> 3 transaction + whilecontroller(10 transactions).

My error would occur at 5th transaction inside while loop. so i need to stop at that 5th transaction level and start the thread again.

ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_CURRENT_LOOP);

So in this case where am not using thread group loop count/duration and using the above code in a Beanshell Postprocessor, it is not moving to next iteration(like stop the current wihle loop run and start from initial). Am I missing something, could someone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

1. It won't, if the error occurs at 5th iteration - "your" code will proceed to 6th iteration without executing any Samplers which are below the Beanshell PostProcessor. According to interpretation of your description with my very limited level of English I believe you need to use [START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.html#START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD) action instead.
2. It's recommended to use JMeter's built-in test elements and avoid scripting where possible. Particular your case can be handled using [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) and [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) Sampler combination
3. If you prefer or have to go for scripting - consider using the most performing language which is Groovy, [it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: Hi Dimitri, I tried this approach to exit the current iteration and start from begining. But looks like it is not working. ctx.setTestLogicalAction(org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContext.TestLogicalAction.START_NEXT_ITERATION_OF_THREAD);